# React-Router: Redirect my url from hashHistory to browserHistory

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, reactjs, redirect, react-router

I've recently make a change to my code to use `browserHistory` instead of `hashHistory` with my React-Router. Although some users of the website I work on might have bookmarked the URL with the hash.

The old url looks like `www.mywebsite.com/#/page?query=param` and I want to make sure if someone bookmarked it, it gets redirected to `www.mywebsite.com/page?query=param`.

It looks like this redirect is not possible with `.htaccess` so I was wondering what would be the cleanest way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: if the user clicks on the url that still has the hash in it, do they get to the site at all?

Comment: There is no hash on links anymore. I'm only concerned about bookmarked or external links pointing to the site. They access the site yes but not the right page.

Answer (score -1):

In you main component, the one were you presumably render `{this.props.children}` you can get access to the current url by calling `this.props.location.pathname` and if the url contains a hash, you can strip it and redirect the user to the url they wanted to go to.

This will only work when the user is first returning to your site from anywhere else, but if they are already on your site and use the bookmark to go elsewhere on the site I dont think this will work. The reason is that the componentDidMount of the main component only fires on initial load or actual page refresh.

Hope this helps.